# Can i store more than 8000 character in a field of SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Facing a challenge to store more than 8000 character, but don't wanted to use nvarChar(max) because it will impact on performance.

Is there any way to store character up-to 15000 character in a field without using nvarChar(max)?
And is there any possibility to get increase size of a field dynamically according to data size without use of nvarChar?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: BTW, a table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto...`TEXT` is depricated, there is **no** good reason to use it.

Comment: @jarlh SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: @HoneyBadger In which DBMS is `TEXT` deprecated? [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-character.html) documentation does not mention deprecation...

Comment: Your concerns for performance are more likely than not entirely in your imagination. `VARCHAR(MAX)` (or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`) *is* the way to store long strings in SQL, and they don't take up any more space than necessary. Your concern for "increasing the size dynamically" suggests you think `MAX` implies some sort of unreasonably large preallocated type. Not only is that not true, but even the decision to store the data in-row or out of row is made depending on the actual size of the string. You'd be hard pressed to beat it for efficiency by using a different approach.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto...I was referring to the dbms actually in use by OP: sql server.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto it has been deprecated in sql server for almost 15 years. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kind of yes, but this gets messy rapidly, and in fact the work around would be worse performance than the varchar(max) option. The issue is the limit of 8060 bytes is permitted on-page for a single row. You can exceed that limit but as long as you accept the data being stored off-page and on a page elsewhere.

Preferred Option : use Varchar(Max) and allow LOB storage to be used.

Alternative : Use multiple varchar(8000) fields, and split / concatenate your string - the data will get Short Large Object'ed (SLOB) and the varchar(8000) fields will be stored off in different pages. This will make it less performant - not to mention the split / concatenate performance issues.

2nd Alternative - compress the data, but there is no guarentee you can still store it within the 8k limit.

Deprecated : Text - do not use this as a solution

In short - do not try to avoid varchar(max) - you would make your life a lot worse.

Comment: Was tying out when I saw this. An excellent, short answer with all pertinent information covered. Nice one. The only thing I would add is that VARCHAR(MAX) is a better option than NVARCHAR(MAX) in "most" situations unless you absolutely require the unicode ability of NVARCHAR as it takes up additional space to store the same data.